# Can you obtain detailed date information on publications when using Google Scholar?

Tags: literature-search, google-scholar

My question is related to [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com). I know that I can search articles by specified year or year range, but is it possible to obtain detailed dates of publication/indexing in Google Scholar? If so, how could I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes.

There is no way to search by more specific date ranges but an exact date might be available for a particular paper. For example, [this](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=V7gfCwsAAAAJ&citation_for_view=V7gfCwsAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C) paper shows a publication date of 2014/4/26 but [this](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=V7gfCwsAAAAJ&citation_for_view=V7gfCwsAAAAJ:9yKSN-GCB0IC) paper only shows the year, 2015, but no month or day.

Otherwise, if Google Scholar doesn't show the date, you can follow the link to the publisher's website which might have it. For example, IEEE lists that second paper as having a conference date of "Sept. 29 2015-Oct. 1 2015."

Comment: Yes, I've found this differentiation and tried also "step by step" digging method but it's very time consuming and works occasionally. But what about indexing date in scholar database?

Comment: @MichalSzulc I'm not quite sure what you mean. My typical workflow is to collect all the bibtex snippets (from the publisher, not Google Scholar, since it is often missing info) for any paper that I might find useful in the future. Then I can use my bibtex manager to search on dates or anything else.

Comment: What do you mean by "from the publisher, not Google Scholar"? Do you always contact publisher by email/phone and ask for a copy?

I'm curious of a date when google scholar indexed searched document in its database. Something like this: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/02/google-shows-when-it-first-indexed-page.html (however this engine descibes in fact **last** date of indexing/crawling, not the first one )